# Почему не получается создать объект класса, унаследованного от шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, наследование, полиморфизм

Есть вот такие 2 шаблонных класса

```
template <typename DataType>
class IGeoIndexer {
public:
    virtual void Insert(const DataType& object, const GeoIndex::Coordinate& coordinate) = 0;
    virtual ~IGeoIndexer() = 0;
};
template<typename DataType>
IGeoIndexer<DataType>::~IGeoIndexer() {

}

template <typename DataType>
class QuadTreeGeoIndexer : public IGeoIndexer<DataType>{
private:
    static const size_t optimalDeep = 14;
    QuadTree<DataType, std::vector<DataType>> quadTree;
public:
    QuadTreeGeoIndexer();
    QuadTreeGeoIndexer(const Coordinate& northWest, const Coordinate& northEast,
                       const Coordinate& southWest, const Coordinate& southEast, size_t deep = optimalDeep);
    ~QuadTreeGeoIndexer() override = default;
    void Insert(DataType data, const GeoIndex::Coordinate& coordinate) override;
};

template<typename DataType>
QuadTreeGeoIndexer<DataType>::QuadTreeGeoIndexer() :
    quadTree(worldNorthWest, worldNorthEast, worldSouthWest, worldSouthEast, optimalDeep)
{
}

template<typename DataType>
QuadTreeGeoIndexer<DataType>::QuadTreeGeoIndexer(const Coordinate &northWest, const Coordinate &northEast,
                                                 const Coordinate &southWest, const Coordinate& southEast, size_t deep) :
                                                 quadTree(northWest, northEast, southWest, southEast, deep)
{
}

template<typename DataType>
void QuadTreeGeoIndexer<DataType>::Insert(DataType data, const GeoIndex::Coordinate &coordinate) {
    Coordinate coord(coordinate.latitude(), coordinate.longitude());
    quadTree.CreateOrFindQuadrant(data, coord, [](const DataType data, std::vector<DataType> dataContainer,
            const Coordinate&, bool){
        dataContainer.push_back(data);
    });
}
```

Я пытаюсь создать объект класса QuadTreeGeoIndexer

```
int main() {
    IGeoIndexer<int>* GeoIndexer = new QuadTreeGeoIndexer<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Но компилятор выдает мне ошибку.

> In instantiation of template class 'QuadTreeGeoIndexer'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтоб я мог сконструировать класс наследник из указателя предка.

Comment: У `virtual ~IGeoIndexer() = 0;` тело есть?

Comment: Следует привести текст ошибки.

Comment: @EOF, есть, с телом вроде рантайм ошибка, а тут не дает скомпилировать

Comment: @user7860670, это и есть весь текст ошибки

Comment: Не может быть...

Comment: @user7860670, я привел скрин, в Clion нажал copy problem description, больше ничего нет

Comment: Не знаю, на кой вам сдался Clion, но за ошибкой в нем надо лезть в лог сборки компилятора в окошке Messages/

Comment: это не ошибка, а предупреждение о неиспользуемой переменной... из явных ошибок — неверно переопределён `Insert`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, вы были правы

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это ошибка - для них показывается красный кружок с вскл знаком.

Comment: @user7860670, там где красный кружок вообще текст гнуто-кленговского примечания...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это оттого, что парсер ошибок скверно работает.